# Double Jump turns into Triple Jump sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a counter to implement double jump, but it only works sometimes. The character is able to triple jump from time to time.

```
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Transform grounded;
    public LayerMask playerMask;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    bool isGrounded;
    float distToGround;
    int counter;
    void Start()
    {
   
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Physics.OverlapSphere(grounded.position, 0.2f, playerMask).Length > 0)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
 
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && counter < 2)
        {
            counter++;
            rb.AddForce(0, 1000, 0);
        }
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, -50, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The Player Mask is set to everything except for the character itself.
[image]

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: When did Triple Jump happen? when you press jump button too fast while character is not fully leave the ground?

Comment: Maybe on the first frame after the player is of the ground the sphere sometimes still overlap with the ground and resets the counter. You can try adding additional condition together with the OverlapSphere - rb.velocity.y <= 0.0f.

Comment: I can't seem to find the pattern for triple jump, it seems to happen randomly. I thought it was the problem of the sphere, so I tried to modify its radius so that it's the smallest possible value that it still returns true when on ground, however triple jump still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I think it was the problem of FixedUpdate() and Update(). I tried to move the ground check and jump code to FixedUpdate(), and Update() only checks for if the space button is pressed. So I initialized a bool variable jumped in Updated(), whenever space is pressed, jumped is set to true. And in FixedUpdate(), before applying force to the character, check if jumped is true. I am new to Unity and I'm not sure why this happens, I'm guessing it's because Update() and FixedUpdate() run on different speed, so they need to have an extra condition to align them.
Thanks for all the helps!